# Переложить вложенный цикл на stream api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Как можно переложить следующий вложенный цикл на stream api?

```
for(int i = 0; i < quantity; i+=2) {
     for(int x = 0; x < someValue; x++, i++){
          System.out.println(i);
     }
}
```

Comment: Для чего это вам?

Comment: Мне интересен кейс, когда это было бы выражено в виде стримов. Есть предложения?

Comment: Стримы не подойдут в данном случае. Вложенный цикл изменяет переменную внешнего цикла, а стримы не должны работать с _состоянием_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто берём всю последовательность чисел и откидываем лишнее:

```
int range = (int) (Math.ceil(1.0 * quantity / (2 + someValue)) * (2 + someValue));
IntStream
    .range(0, range)
    .filter(x -> (x + 1) % (someValue + 2) != 0 && (x + 2) % (someValue + 2) != 0)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Вот это то, что я искал. Спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Ваш цикл (при `someValue >= 0`) эквивалентен следующему:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i += 2 + someValue) {
        for (int x = 0; x < someValue; x++) {
            System.out.println(i + x);
        }
    }
```

Его можно заменить на

```
    int until = Math.ceil(quantity / (2 + someValue)); // see @zRrr comment
    for (int i = 0; i < until; i++) {
        final int i0 = i * (2 + someValue);
        IntStream.range(0, someValue).forEach(x -> System.out.println(i0 + x));
    }
```

И далее на

```
    int until = Math.ceil(quantity / (2 + someValue));
    IntStream.range(0,  until).forEach(i -> {
        final int i0 = i * (2 + someValue);
        IntStream.range(0, someValue).forEach(x -> System.out.println(i0 + x));
    });
```

Comment: А за что минус?

Comment: кмк границу внешнего цикла нужно округлять вверх, и вместо двух `forEach` можно использовать `flatMap( i -> range(..).map( .. )`

Comment: @zRrr, `map` нет смысла использовать для процедуры, а значит, нет смысла и во `flatMap`. А за внешнюю границу спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: @MikhailIonkin да тут вообще нет смысла использовать стримы. Но если уж использовать механизмы функционального программирования, то использовать их стоит в соответствии с идиомами ФП, а не в процедурном стиле.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev так вопрос нацелен именно на стримы. А имеет это смысла или нет, решать автору вопроса. И вы путаете процедурный и императивный стили: в ФП допустим forEach

Comment: @MikhailIonkin видимо, автор - новичок и не понимает, что хочет странного. Лучше не давать новичкам плохих советов. Нет, именно процедурный стиль я имел ввиду. Этим я хотел подчеркнуть, что ваш код напоминает код людей, которые обходят встроенный в Java ОПП, распихивая весь функционал по статическим методам одного класса.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, а чем плохо иногда использовать статические методы? Кроме того, `forEach` тут не статический, а вот `range` иначе чем как через статический метод не получишь (по крайней мере, я не знаю способа). Критикуя меня за использование статических методов, вы тем самым критикуете разработчиков Java 8

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а автор мог преследовать цель переноса аналогичных конструкций в функциональный язык, например, Clojure. И в нем, между прочим, есть `forEach` (в виде `(1..3).each`)

Comment: @MikhailIonkin вы меня не поняли.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin вы Clojure с Groovy путаете.

Comment: @Hivemaster спасибо, но в Clojure тоже есть `forEach`: `(doseq [i [0 1 2 3]] (println i))`